# Programatic block with default configuration form?

Tags: 7, blocks, features

We're using features on our Drupal project. We would like to specify few blocks NEED to be present in the database and their settings. Imagine block named "sidebar advertisement". That block has certain settings (display on certain content types like "Basic page", or certain URLs). We don't really care about the block's contents. That's admin's responsibility.

Is there a way to enforce the existence and settings of this block, but keep the rest the same (the editing form, etc.)? There are ways to create blocks programatically using `hook_block_info()`, but that requires implementing custom persistence for the block's contents using `hook_block_configure()`.

Comment: So you have a form in a block. What are the settings you'd like to export? Have you considered strongarm or features block module?

Comment: I've found something that does the trick, but I am not sure how to hook it in - https://www.drupal.org/node/1709954#comment-8592077

Comment: The trouble with the above is checking whether the block already exists and it has all the required params